# Setting a CSS class by URL with ColdFusion

Tags: css, coldfusion, cfml

In the code below, I'm looking to set the `li` class as "active" pro grammatically with ColdFusion based on the url that I'm currently on. So in this example, I've landed at main.cfm and need to set that specific `li` class to active. If I'm at www.mysite.com/review.cfm I'd like to set that class as "active".

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="main.cfm">Main</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="review.cfm" title="">Review</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="https://www.mysite.com">My Site</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="reporting">Reporting</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ColdFusion 9:

```
<cfset class = ListLast(cgi.Script_Name, '/') EQ "main.cfm" ? "active" : "">
<li class="#class#"><a href="main.cfm">Main</a></li>
```

ColdFusion 8 or below, use good old `<cfif>`

```
<cfset class = "">
<cfif ListLast(cgi.Script_Name, '/') EQ "main.cfm">
   <cfset class = "active">
</cfif>
<li class="#class#"><a href="main.cfm">Main</a></li>
```

**UPDATE**: OR as KRC suggested in the comment (ColdFusion 8 or below):

```
<li IIF(ListLast(cgi.Script_Name, '/') EQ "main.cfm", DE('class="active"'), '')>
  <a href="main.cfm">Main</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Instead of having to hardcode the `Right( cgi.Script_Name, 8 )` you'd be better off using `ListLast( cgi.Script_Name, '/' )`

Comment: Oh `GetFileFromPath()` works too.  It's about the same in terms of readability.

Comment: iif works here also. <li#iif(ListLast(cgi.Script_Name, '/') EQ "main.cfm",DE('class="active"'),DE(''))#>Main</li>

Comment: @KRC yes, that's as good as you can write it before CF9's ternary operator.  However I would really suggest against using it, because whatever in `DE()` will be evaluated by `Evaluate()`.

Comment: @Henry, I have to disagree with your suggestion that it shouldn't be used here.  The tag is called an inline if; I feel this kind of problem is a great example of exactly where it should be used.  I would use a ternary if I needed to control the output of the same value multiple times on the same page.  If he has a reason to set that CSS class more than once on the page, then I would favor your solution more.  The impact on performance for using Evaluate vs the ternary here is IMO, not worth the effort for the extra line of code.  Either way, either answer solves the problem. :)

Comment: @KRC `class="#ListLast(cgi.Script_Name, '/') EQ 'main.cfm' ? 'active' : ''#"` the ternary operator statement can be a one-liner, and IMO it's superior than `iff()` and `de()` in readability & performance. :)

Comment: @KRC added your suggestion to the answer, if you don't mind. :)

Comment: @Henry - Not at all.  I didn't even think about using ternary inline like that, though it should have been obvious, and it's definitely more readable then an iif.